# android best practice for big grid of views performance

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, drawing, android-canvas

I want to create a very big grid around 30 x 30 in size.
Every view in the grid is clickable and every click change the look of the view, Until now I tried:

- Nesting  Horizontal `LinearLayout` inside Vertical `LinearLayout`
- `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`
- Drawing the grid as a `Bitmap` on `Canvas` and updating each time cell clicked

Any one of this options wasn't good enough in means of performance, do you have any other idea for this? Or maybe a better way to one of this options?

This grid is an Example of grid 20x20 after some click changes
[image: An example grid]

Comment: When you used a Canvas, did you update the whole grid when a cell was clicked or only the cell(s) that actually changed?